# How to structure a Python project to have Unit Tests

Tags: python, pytest, python-packaging, pythonpath

I am facing difficulties to get the module's references in the Unit Test files.

This is my level 1:

```
$ backend-app

├── Dockerfile
├── __init__.py
├── app
├── credentials-dev.json
├── requirements.txt
├── tests
└── venv
```

This is my Unit `tests` directory:

```
$ backend-app.tests

├── __init__.py
├── integration
│   ...
└── unit
    ├── __init__.py
    └── util
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_convert_utils.py
```

This is the module (`convert_utils.py`) file I want to access to test:

```
$ backend-app.app

├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── resources
│   ├── config-dev.yaml
│   └── credentials-dev.json
└── src
    ├── impl
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── transaction_impl.py
    │   └── transaction_validation.py
    ├── model
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   └── transaction.py
    ├── service
        ...
    └── util
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── convert_utils.py
```

**Question**: how to reference the `convert_utils.py` inside the `test_convert_utils.py` by relative or absolute path? As it is, I haven't found any way to achieve that.

Comment: You have a package named `util`; presumably `test_convert_utils.py` would like to simply use `import util.convert_utils` or similar. All you need to do is ensure that `src` is in the module search path when you execute the tests. How you do that depends on how you running the test suite.

Comment: Ok, so how to configure it to module search path?

Comment: Reread the last sentence of my comment.